# Scroll bar in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a scrollable div in bootstrap grid system. But its not working. Without bootstrap I am able to get scrollbar. Here is my fiddle. Within bootstrap I don't get scrollbar but outside bootstrap grid I get scrollbar.  I am trying to achieve scrollbar without fixing the height of outer div. I can't use max-height because it won't increase after certain height.

http://jsfiddle.net/gurukashyap/k4rwo80z/8/

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div id="container">

    <div id="fixeddiv-top">FIXED DIV (TOP)</div>
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="content">CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div id="fixeddiv-bottom">FIXED DIV (BOTTOM)</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



      </div>
      <div >

      </div>
    </div>
</div>    
            <br/><br/>
Without bootstrap Grid scroll works!!

             <div id="container">

    <div id="fixeddiv-top">FIXED DIV (TOP)</div>
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="content">CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div id="fixeddiv-bottom">FIXED DIV (BOTTOM)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/k4rwo80z/11/) In this update I added a little `jQuery` I assign the height of the screen to the `#content` so you will also get the same effect as `height=100%`.

[Your sample I edited](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/k4rwo80z/14/)

**Additional info that might help you** :

In this line : `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` you can change the `width` of the `div` based on grid-system of bootstrap. There are 4 classes on that div.

1. `col-lg-12` this class is recognize when the `width` screen is greater than `1200px`. You can change the number accordingly. `12` would be the full size of the grid system, `6` would be half of the full size of the grid system, `4` is 3/4 of the full size of the grid system etc.
2. `col-sm-12` is recognize when the screen `width` is equal or greater than `768px`. Same rule applies for the numbers.
3. `col-md-12` is recognize when the screen `width` is greater than `992px`. Same rule for the numbers.
4. `col-xs-12` si recognize if the screen `width` is less than `768px` thus mobile devices. All grid number here is equivalent to the full size of the grid system. For example if you use `col-xs-12` the width will be 100% same as when you use `col-xs-1` it will also be 100% same goes for 2, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: Hi I don't want to fix the height of container. In bigger screens resolutions it will have fixed height which i don't want. I want it to occupy entire available viewport.

Comment: Actually as far as I know you can't achieve scrolling if you have a `width` set to 100% because it will just push the bottom of the div no matter how many content you put. You should use jQuery to assign a height for the div. See update to my answer.

Comment: The `height` attribute on `css` will be overriden by the `jQuery` `height`.

Comment: Yeah i agree if you look at below example height is set to 100% but still scroll works. Same if i put inside bootstrap column it does not work.http://jsfiddle.net/gurukashyap/2Lj296q4/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/k4rwo80z/14/ There. It is now inside the bootstrap `col` and the scroll works. Its just the same as what ive done to my answer but I will explain again just so it will be clear for you. If it is inside bootstrap column without the `jQuery` I added it will not work.